# How to get and post common data to each request made to the web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient

I have created a simple webapi service with few get/post methods,  these methods are having some input parameters that client is passing while making call to it, other than these parameter I have some common parameters that has to pass in each request made to the web api, currently I added in every web api method as input parameter that is passing by client along with other input parameters. I am looking for a way where I don'n need to add these common parameters on every webapi method, I want to get these common parameters commonly under webapi.

This is my sample api controller

```
public class MessageController : ApiController
{
    //companyID is a common parameter that is required to pass every web api method  

    public IHttpActionResult GetMessage(string messageCode, int companyID)
    {
        Message msg = null;
        MesssageManager msgManager = null;
        try
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(messageCode))
            {
                throw new Exception("Plase pass the messageCode in order to get the message.");
            }
            msgManager = new MesssageManager();
            List<Message> messages = msgManager.GetMessages(companyID);
            msg = messages.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Code.Equals(messageCode, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            return Ok(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            msgManager = null;
        }
    }

public IHttpActionResult GetWarningMessage(string warningCode, int companyID)
    {
        //doing actual stuff to get the data 
    }

public IHttpActionResult GetMthod1(string param1, int companyID)
    {
        //doing actual stuff to get the data 
    }

public IHttpActionResult GetMthod2(string param1, int companyID)
    {
        //doing actual stuff to get the data 
    }

[HttpPost]
 public IHttpActionResult SaveMessage(string message, int companyID)
        {
            //doing actual stuff to get the data 
        }

}
```

In above controller "companyID" is a common parameter that has to pass in each request.

Please suggest me implementation in web api to get the common parameters, and how to pass it from client using HttpClient.

Answer (score 1):

If the companyID is some kind of indentification/authentication parameter you could add the companyId to the request headers. Implement an [authenticationfilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters) and grab the companyId from the headers. However, you still need some kind of short term persisting mechanism (session, cache, scoped DI container etc.) where the authentication filter would store the parameter and the controller method would get the parameter from.

At the end you need to pass the parameter from the client to the server each time it is required. You need to figure out if it's less hassle to put it into the headers or pass it as a parameter to the method. If the companyId varies from request to request I'd add it to each method. If the companyId is "static" for at least a duration of a session then I'd put it into the headers and would try to make sure, that the client automatically adds the appropriate companyId to the request headers (i.e. like you would handle user tokens).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below line 
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/574576/How-to-implement-a-custom-IPrincipal-in-ASP-NET-MV

**We can add additional attribute in CustomPrincipalSerializedModel like below**

```
public interface ICustomPrincipal : System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }

    string LastName { get; set; }

    int CompanyId { get;set; }
}
public class CustomPrincipal : ICustomPrincipal
{
    public IIdentity Identity { get; private set; }

    public CustomPrincipal(string username)
    {
        this.Identity = new GenericIdentity(username);
    }

    public bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        return Identity != null && Identity.IsAuthenticated && 
           !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(role) && Roles.IsUserInRole(Identity.Name, role);
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }

    public int CompanyId { get;set; }
}

public class CustomPrincipalSerializedModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get;set; }
}
```

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/574576/How-to-implement-a-custom-IPrincipal-in-ASP-NET-MV

Answer (score -1):

We can get from header or cookies or use Custom identity principals

Comment: Please refer below line 
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/574576/How-to-implement-a-custom-IPrincipal-in-ASP-NET-MV